# confusion about the new keyword inside a static method

Tags: c#

I'm trying to achieve a good optimization in a performance critical section of my program.

So my question is, does the `char[] abcdef` gets re-created every time I call `CountAbcdef()` because of the `new` keyword? Should I move it outside and declare as **static** or not?

```
private static int CountAbcdef(string s)
{
    var abcdef = new[] { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' };
    return s.Count(abcdef.Contains);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: yes, that will be initialized every time CountAbcdef is called. You could create a static array that is referenced by a static method, which would be initialized once.

Comment: Yes it does get created every time you call this function. Should you change something to optimise this? Profile. If it's a problem, change it.

Comment: @KRichardson Thank you! Maybe you should give an answer so I can accept it? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right in that the array will be initialized every time CountAbcdef is called this way. An alternative way would be to create a static array that is initialized by a static method, then the Count method can reference the pre-initialized array.

Answer (score 2):

The memory is allocated every time the method is run, not because of the new keyword.  The following method would have the exact same effect as the provided method and there is no new keyword. The memory is dereferenced at the end of the method, so there memory impact is minimal.

```
private static int CountAbcdef(string s)
{
    var abcdef = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' };
    return s.Count(abcdef.Contains);
}
```

If you want to optimize the method, you can move the array outside of the method and make it static.  The array would be initialized only one time, at the first usage of the class.  To prevent the static array reference from being changed use the readonly keyword.

```
readonly static char[] abcdef = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' };
private static int CountAbcdef(string s)
{
    return s.Count(abcdef.Contains);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use LINQ in performance critical sections. You can avoid the [overhead](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,d35db0dea6ae310a,references):

```
private static int CountAbcdef(string s)
{
    int count = 0;
    foreach (char c in s)
        if ( c >= 'a' && c <= 'f' ) 
            count++;
    return count;
}
```